# General regarding grammar and conjugation of tempi

Tags: tense, conjugation

I have three related questions to German grammar and conjugation of tempi.

#### Perfekt

> Ich habe Urlaub gehabt.

First person singular, present, *haben.* Where does the *gehabt* come from?

#### Plusquamperfekt

Ich hatte Urlaub gehabt.

First person singular, imperfect, *haben.* Where does the *gehabt* come from?

#### Futur

> Ich werde Urlaub haben.

First person singular, *werden.* Why the infinitive of *haben?*

Comment: Have you looked in your grammar book? What do you mean saying "where does it come from"? It is the way these tempi are built.

Comment: The questions I have surfaced ***after*** I consulted the grammar book.

Comment: I have **had** a vacation. I had **had** a vacation. I will **have** a vacation. Not so different from English, is it?

Comment: @Carsten: I do not challenge that at all. I am curious about the "gehabt" construction.

Comment: "Gehabt" is Partizip 2 of "haben". And you need Partizip 2 for Perfekt, Plusquamperfekt and other things.

Comment: @Alex: Excellent! This part of the puzzle was not covered at all in the grammar book. They just list the constructions and slap a name and that is it. If you slap what you answered in the comment I will award you the points.

Comment: *gehabt* is the past participle of the verb *haben*. I find it difficult to understand what your question is.

Comment: @Carsten: Check my response to Alex S.

Comment: Any grammar book "slaps" what AlexS said.

Comment: @AlexS: Em1 is challenging your expertise.

Comment: What kind of grammar book for any language does not cover verb tenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only English, but also German has auxiliary verbs.

> Ich<sub>1</sub> habe<sub>2</sub> Urlaub<sub>3</sub> gehabt<sub>4</sub>.
>   I<sub>1</sub> have<sub>2</sub> had<sub>4</sub> holidays<sub>3</sub>.
>
> Ich<sub>1</sub> habe<sub>4</sub> Urlaub<sub>3</sub>.
>   I<sub>1</sub> have<sub>4</sub> holidays<sub>3</sub>.

compare with

> Ich<sub>1</sub> habe<sub>2</sub> Pizza<sub>3</sub> gegessen<sub>4</sub>.
>   I<sub>1</sub> have<sub>2</sub> eaten<sub>4</sub> pizza<sub>3</sub>.
>
> Ich<sub>1</sub> aß<sub>4</sub> Pizza<sub>3</sub>.
>   I<sub>1</sub> ate<sub>4</sub> pizza<sub>3</sub>.

The words with the numbers 2 and 4 together build the predicate. One of them (#2) is an auxiliary verb that is here for grammatical reasons to build the grammatical tense. The other (#4) is a full verb that transports a meaning (what is happening in the sentence?)

In the above example the words in both languages match 1:1, just the word-order is different. (1:1-matching is generally rare, but here we had good luck.)

---

There are three verbs that are used as auxiliary verbs in German. They are:

- haben (to have)

  > Ich **habe** die Suppe gegessen. (I **have** eaten the soup.)
  >   Ich **habe** sehr lange geschlafen. (I **did** sleep very long.)
- sein (to be)

  > Ich **bin** mit dem Bus gefahren. (I **have** been going by bus.)
  >   Maria **ist** schon eingeschlafen. (Maria already **did** fall asleep.)
- werden (to become)

  > Ich **werde** gewinnen. (I **will** win.)
  >   Der Prinz **wurde** in einen Frosch verzaubert. (The prince **was** enchanted into a frog.)

(You can learn from some examples, that the usage of auxiliary verbs is not always the same in English and German.)

But all three verbs also can be used as full verbs:

> Erich **hat** Hunger. (Literally: Erich **has** hunger. Meaning: Erich is hungry.)
>   Arno **ist** Italiener. (Arno **is** Italien.)
>   Eisen **wird** zu Rost. (Iron **becomes**/turns into rust.)

And when you have a sentence, where one of this full verbs has to be used together with an auxiliary verb for grammatical reasons, then you have sentences like

> Erich hat Hunger gehabt.

Here »hat« is the auxiliary verb and »gehabt« is the full verb. Both verbs together build the predicate, and here by coincidence both are forms of the same verb which is »haben«.

And this is exactly what happend in your examples.

Comment: Vielen Dank, Hubert!

Comment: "werden" as auxiliary ist just not "to become".